# Error Thunderbird v 60.5.1 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: email, thunderbird

I am having this error, since this morning when I switch on my computer and tried to launch Thunderbird: “Unable to load address book file abook.mab. It may be read-only, or locked by another application. Please try again later.”
Moreover I lost all the emails addresses which were set up in Thunderbird, 25 addresses. I am not an Ubuntu specialist, just a simple basic user. 
I found a post almost equivalent here : 
[Mozilla Thunderbird Error (38.5.1)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/731577/mozilla-thunderbird-error-38-5-1/1128537?noredirect=1#comment1868513_1128537)
I wanted to try the solutions but :
- I don't want to use "touch" command, as I don't want to create a new address book, but recover my address book and the email addresses I already set up .
- I couldn't find "abook.mab" or "abook.mab.bak" files on my computer, therefore I was not able to try the second option described by @Ramesh Chand.
Thanks for any help
JP S

Comment: really? in a terminal `find -name "*abook*" 2>/dev/null` returns nothing? I get `./.thunderbird/l0w22ubs.default/abook.mab`

Comment: @tatsu
Here under is the copy of the screen, when typing in terminal the command you gave me, which I didn't know, neither understand. I am just a basic user, sorry ...
[link] joel-pol@JPS-X230:~$ find -name "*abook*" 2>/dev/null
joel-pol@JPS-X230:~$
Sorry I put the asterik before and after abook, but they dont show in the post ...

Comment: okay yeah that file is well and truely gone (that command is a finder. `find` finds thing you want to find. in this case the criteria for finding was a name, hence `-name` then in between the quotes comes the name you're looking for `abook` bracketted by two wildcards : `*` which allow the search to broaden to anything before or after those sets of characters and lastly `2>/dev/null` silences the errors because find whines alot while in the process of going through folders and files if any of them need admin priveleges to be read.)

Comment: in ubuntu or linux when you run a command in the terminal and you just get a new line without it saying anything, that means the command ran successfully with nothing to add. hence find found nothing matching our criteria. you have no adress book on your system. I'm sorry, I'll pass the flag to whoever wants I don't think I have a solution in this case. did you by any chance set up ubuntu automated backups?

Comment: OK, thank you very much @tatsu , much clearier when I understand, even though I am not at all an IT specialist. Do you think that I may recover it if I use the yesterday or tonight backup of my computer ? I set up backup of Ubuntu to run everyday.

Comment: yes actually. there's a good chance. when files are deleted they aren't scrubbed off your disk, that would take too long, their adress is simply removed from "the registry of files". media recovery works by browsing the disk without assumtions based on the registry and actually looking at what looks like the begining and the ending of a file. it can even find several states for one file sometimes. so there's a good chance a recovery guy can get it to you.

Comment: Actually I run this morning the following commands :     
- sudo apt-get autoclean    
- sudo apt-get clean    
- sudo apt-get autoremove    
Maybe it was my mistake ....

Comment: oh interesting. this may have been the cause.

Comment: A recovery guy ? So that would mean I should find a specialist in Linux/Ubuntu here in Sofia. I will try to find one than ... if this is better than using the recovering by backup

Comment: Actually I took this commands from how to clean Ubuntu on the ubuntu forum ...

Comment: I tried to recover backups from last night, this morning at 02:13, and yesterday, and it didn't work. I will now try to find a way to uninstall properly Thunderbird with all "hiden" components and reinstall it in a clear and proper way and set it up all again.

Comment: so you're giving up on your address book? any computer store worth their salt (IE not at big giant shopping mall) but a small boutique will have people who use linux day-to-day. or you could learn to use recovery tools. it's really not black magic.

Comment: Thanks for you support and help @tatsu, I fully reinstalled Thunderbird with all email addresses. As I said I am a basic user, and don't have time to spend on learning new IT things, I am enough busy with works and family ;)

Comment: ok. since the adress book has a tendency to be dropped in the middle of a write by Thunderbird (rendering it unreadable by the file system) make sure to make a copy of this file, to keep in another folder just in case this happens again.